# Sonarqube - How to resolve 'Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor'

Tags: sonarqube

Help! I keep receiving the 'Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor' error? I've tried reinstalling jdk and I've already set up the JAVA_HOME directory correctly. Any other ways I can fix this?

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:606)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponents(DefaultPicoContainer.java:587)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentsByType(ComponentContainer.java:291)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.completeScannerExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:82)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getFilteredExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:67)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary.selectSensors(ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary.java:40)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:52)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:52)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:388)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:384)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:381)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:353)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.(ActionParser.java:59)
> at org.sonar.javascript.parser.JavaScriptParser.(JavaScriptParser.java:33)
> at org.sonar.javascript.parser.JavaScriptParserBuilder.createParser(JavaScriptParserBuilder.java:31)
> at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor.(JavaScriptSensor.java:115)
> at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor.(JavaScriptSensor.java:85)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
> at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
> at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
> at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
> at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
> at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
> at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
> at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
> at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
> at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
> ... 47 more
> Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make
> protected final java.lang.Class
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does
> not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @43d9f1a2
> at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
> at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:73)
> ... 67 more
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does
> not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @43d9f1a2
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.(ReflectUtils.java:52)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
> ... 79 more
> ERROR:
> The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
> 19:54:27.606  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Comment: This is not a complete stack trace. Please include a complete trace up to the last message (as text, not as an image).

Comment: I also have this problem - did you find a resolution?